# r dygraphs not showing plots

Tags: r, r-dygraphs

I installed and updated the dygraphs and htmlwidgets packages, but the values are not showing. I used many example code all of them are not showing value plots but only a frame with 0-1 y-axes.

```
library(dygraphs)
dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures", ylab = "Temp (F)")
```

I expected the result as the example from here http://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/r-markdown.html

But it only shows a title, y-lab, y-lim(from 0-1), and a 16:00 at the beginning of x-axes.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. I get a graphic with blue-green connected segments. `sessionInfo()` returns `R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS`

Comment: Try restarting R, running the code you posted, then pasting your `sessionInfo()` as an edit to the post. The sessionInfo you provided in a comment doesn't say which versions of `dygraphs` and `htmlwidgets` you have.

Comment: For the record I had dygraphs_1.1.1.6 and htmlwidgets_1.3 in my successful running of that code.